# Extract second element from every item in a list and other questions

Tags: r

Here is what I am trying to do:
This throws more light but here is what I am trying to. Lets say you have a data like the one below –

```
Region      Open    Store
120..141       +    France
145..2115      +    Germany
3322..5643     +    Wales
5646..7451     -    Scotland
7454..8641     -    Mexico
8655..9860     -    India
9980..11413    +    Zambia
11478..1261    -    Nicaragua
12978..1318    +    Sweeden
```

What I was trying to do was to pick find the difference between the second element (141) and the consecutive first element (145) and if they meet a certain value and they have the same sign ( + or -), group the stores together. Example of the output

### Desired output should be like (if the numbers difference is less than 40 and the store signs are the same (either having the same + or -)

```
 4 (France and Germany)
 3,14 (Scotland and Mexico and india)
```

Comment: Do you mean 145 for the "consecutive first element"? Can you add the desired output to the question?

Comment: Yes I meant 145, I hope the extra information helps you to fully understand

Comment: Can you change your desired output so that it is formatted and looks exactly like what you want R to spit out? Right now it really doesn't help anyone understand what you are asking.

Comment: Does the new format help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector of "second elements" (not really elements) in the case of a "character" vector is `sapply( strsplit(dat$Region, "\\.\\.") , "[", 2)` and the "first elements" `sapply( strsplit(dat$Region, "\\.\\.") , "[", 1)`. Presumably, the first such difference (in the case where `data.frame` made the first column into the default factor class) is:

```
 as.numeric(sapply( strsplit(as.character(dat$Region), "\\.\\.") , "[", 1)[2]) - 
       as.numeric(sapply( strsplit(as.character(dat$Region), "\\.\\.") , "[", 1)[1])
#[1] 25
```

[Note: The need for "\.\." as the 'split' argument comes from the fact that the 'split' argument is interpreted as a regex expression.] The vector of all differences:

```
as.numeric(sapply( strsplit(as.character(dat$Region), "\\.\\.") , "[", 1)[-1]) - 
as.numeric(sapply( strsplit(as.character(dat$Region), "\\.\\.") , "[", 1)[-length(dat$Region)])
[1]   25 3177 2324 1808 1201 1325 1498 1500
```

The rest of your question (and the edits) is failing to communicate your intent (probably on the basis of a lack of a shared natural language. (i have no idea what the phrases "all their stores" and "the store signs" might mean.) Please make an effort to communicate in idoiomatic language.

Comment: I have added some more explanation. I hope this helps

Comment: Also your calculation should be taken diference between the second element and the consecutive first element. I can see that your output calculated the difference between 120 and 145. It should 141 and 145, 2115 and 3322 and so on

Answer (score 0):

This works with the data you provided - I'm a noobie at R so sorry if it's messy.

```
# Split the string in the first column to make it easier to compare
library(stringr)
regionl<-str_split_fixed(data$Region,c("[..]"),3)[,1]
regionr<-str_split_fixed(data$Region,c("[..]"),3)[,3]

data$regionl <- regionl
data$regionr <-regionr

# We set a threshold for comparison
threshold = 100

# Lets loop through the data and check the right column with the left column 
# We see if it is less than the threshold and has the same sign
# We add the groups up until there is a discrepancy and we print

currentGroup = NULL

for(i in 1:(nrow(data)-1))
{

  # Boolean variables checking against signs and thresholds

  difference <- abs(as.numeric(data$regionr[i])-as.numeric(data$regionl[i+1])) <= threshold
  signs <- (data$Open[i] ==  data$Open[i+1])

  # Group things together
  if(difference & signs)
  {
    currentGroup <- c(currentGroup,as.character(data$Store[i]),as.character(data$Store[i+1]))
  }
  else
  {
    # If it's in a group alone, do not print
    if(is.null(currentGroup))
    {
      # Do nothing
    }else
    {
      # Print groups
      print(unique(currentGroup))
    }
    # Reset the group holder
    currentGroup<-NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This worked but it is not <=100 to do the groupings.

Comment: For a large data set that I tried with your code example, the stores being returned do not thereshold of <100. Can you please throw more light?

Comment: Hi! Sure can you please give us the part of the dataset that's not producing the expected result? PS. You can change the threshold to whatever you like ~

Comment: The "Store" is the that is giving the problem.

Comment: currentGroup <- c(currentGroup,as.character(data$Store[i]),as.character(data$Store[i+1])) does not give expected result. Any insight

Comment: Hi can you give me a new data set to test?